# What is the maximum length of a Static Resource name?

Tags: static-resources

I'm working on a feature that will create static resources and give them an automatic name. While I don't expect these names to be particularly long, I was wondering if there's a name length limit I need to be concerned about. I couldn't find anything about limits on a Static Resource's Name, just it's [Body/Content](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources.htm).

Answer (score 4):

I tried creating a Static Resource with a 100-character name and got the following error:

[image: Error: The Static Resource name and namespace combined must be shorter than 80 characters]

So it appears that the limit on the length of a Static Resource's name is **80 characters**.